# ERROR:native_process_launcher.cc(130)] Can't find manifest for native messaging host com.clockworkmod.adb

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I run angularjs app into chrome and i get weird error in visual studio code console:

> ERROR:native_process_launcher.cc(130)] Can't find manifest for native messaging host com.clockworkmod.adb

I think it's chrome issue because in the console in browser it not show any error.

Comment: The error says you didn't install the additional utility into your OS that adds a special manifest for Chrome to be able to launch it. See [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging),

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this usually means that you need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].